# Removing <style> tags from <head>

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, styles, head

Our forms software generates multiple `<style>` tags in the `<head>` section, none of which are needed (or wanted).

How can I remove them? I tried the following but guess my logic is flawed here...I thought I had to target the parent (the `<head>`) to remove a child element but guess I'm being too simplistic:

```
var hs = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    hs[i].parentNode.removeChild(hs[i]);
}
```

Have I got myself in an array muddle?

Comment: `hs[i].remove()`? But your code works fine for me.

Comment: I think you have to access the parent to remove its child, rather than remove the child directly?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var hs = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
for (var i=0, max = hs.length; i < max; i++) {
    hs[i].parentNode.removeChild(hs[i]);
}
```

You used `max = all.length`, you did not define `all` and I'm guessing you meant `hs.length`.
And `max = hs.length` would be one to many because the array is 0 based.

Comment: Ah, silly mistake - thanks. It removes all '<style>' tags but leaves the last one - I thought this might be the '-1' needing changed but must be something else?